# Is there a collective name for non-ensemble MCMC methods?

Tags: terminology, markov-chain-montecarlo

There is a class of MCMC algorithms which are called "ensemble samplers", so-called because they use an ensemble of walkers whose positions depend on each other to sample from the posterior distribution. The one I'm most familiar with is Goodman and Weare's affine-invariant ensemble sampler, as I have used it with the emcee package which is popular in my field (astrophysics).

Is there a similar word or name for the simpler type of MCMC algorithms in which a single chain is constructed by sampling from the posterior distribution one point at a time? In the "walker" language, it's a chain with a single walker. Multiple chains can be run in parallel in these methods, but they remain completely independent. If I wanted to write a sentence contrasting the two, what word would be used? i.e. "Ensemble sampling methods vs _____ sampling methods".